# How to Compare a single image with multiple images in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to compare a single image (probably jpeg formats) with multiple images in matlab and when the images matches with one of the multiple images i would like to output that image file name.

Comment: i have tried comparing two images and it worked.but i would like to compare one image with multiple images..just not one to one..and i would like to have the code for comparing one image with several images till the image matches(like a loop function).

Comment: OK - so you want to know how to write a loop in MATLAB ?

Comment: yes it may include...but better let me explain an example.there is an image which has to be compared with the several images to find the match.so it starts with some sequence and continues till it matches.so could u plz help me on getting this solved by giving appropriate code. thx

Comment: You can just use a `for` loop, and then use `break` to exit the loop when you find a match. Read up on loops in MATLAB if you have never used them: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/07/19/how-for-works/

Comment: ... or `while ~matched`.

Comment: @lokesh how do tou compared two images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% the basic image that you are trying to find
the_image = imread('compare_image.jpg');
% list of images you are trying to compare to    
% go through each image

end
```

Comment: i donno how to vote you..but you helped me thx.i was in urgent i n getting the code.thx for u r help